# Loop through xml

Tags: c#, xml

```
 <result>
   <email>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Subject>hi</Subject>
   </email>
   <email>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Subject>hi2</Subject>
   </email>
</result>
```

How can I loop through this xml to save Id, Subject in list of objects

Thanks for any help

Comment: what have you tried? just searching for "c# xml" should already give you an idea...

Comment: i have tried to load xml using xmldocument and i searched to for looping but i found examples for xml like <email Id='1' subject='hi' /> . but my xml is different. so how can i write for this

Comment: Loop through XML...Save Id, Subject in objList..

There are lot of examples available online. All you need to do is google or yahoo search it...

Comment: @user1622436 When you search for examples, do you expect an exact match for your case or want to learn something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a eMail class. (you can change the name in the code sample) it should work.

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var songlist = from c in xdoc.Element("Result").Elements("email")
                           select new eMail{ 
                               ID = c.Element("ID").Value, 
                               Subject = c.Element("Subject").Value };
```

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ to XML you can achieve it pretty simply, assuming that you're opening a file:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Load(@"path\to\file.xml");
var result = doc.Element("result");
foreach(var mail in result.Elements("email")) {
    Console.WriteLine("id: {0}\nsubject: {1}",
        (int)mail.Element("Id"),
        (string)mail.Element("Subject"));
}
```